# Prove that if the vectors u, v, and w are in the vector space of V, that the vectors u-v, v-w, and w-u form a linearly dependent set.

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that for something to form a linear dependent set they have to have non-zero scalars that when multiplied by the vector set equals the zero vector. Does this have anything to do with the closure addition axiom? I am a little lost on this one.

Comment: Wouldn't I then have to assume that my constants are not all non-zero for it to be linearly dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(u-v)+(v-w)+(w-u)=0$. So there is a combination of scalars $c_1=c_2=c_3=1\neq 0$ so that $c_1(u-v)+c_2(v-w)+c_3(w-u)=0$. Hence, they are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

To show linear dependence, you want to show that one of the vectors can be written as a linear combination of the others.  So, for example, you could write $w-u = -(u-v)+ -(v-w)$.